# Gradle: how can I delegate to a parent project's resolutionStrategy?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a Gradle parent project that defines a `resolutionStrategy`. I'd like to override the behavior of `eachDependency` for certain dependencies, but delegate to to for the others. How can I do this? How can I get a reference to the parent's resolutionStrategy so I can delegate?

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
      // how can I delegate to the parent here?
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can have multiple `eachDependency` actions, so for my issue, the parent's `eachDependency` already ran, but I can override anything it did in the child's `eachDependency`.

Edit: as requested. In my case, the parent was setting jackson to a different version. This was how I forced it to a specific version in the child `build.gradle`:

```
def jacksonGroups = [
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.module'
] as Set

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
      if (jacksonGroups.contains(details.requested.group)) {
        details.useVersion '2.9.2'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How do you override?

Thank you!